# strpos function issue in PHP not finding the needle

Tags: php, string

In php I have open a .php file and want to evaluate certain lines. Specifically when the $table_id and $line variables are assigned a value.

Within the text file I have:

```
...  
$table_id = 'crs_class';                      // table name
$screen   = 'crs_class.detail.screen.inc';    // file identifying screen structure
...
```

amongst other lines. The if statement below never detects the occurance of `$table_id` or `$screen` (even without the $ prepended). I can't understand why it won't work as the strpos statement below looking for 'require' works fine.

So, why isn't this if statement getting a hit?

```
while ($line=fgets($fh)) {
    //echo "Evaluating... $line <br>";
    **if ((($pos = stripos($line, '$table_id')) === true) || (($pos = stripos($line, '$screen'))===true))**
    {
        // TODO: Not evaluating tableid and screen lines correctly fix.
        // Set $table_id and $screen variables from task scripts
        eval($line);
    }

    if (($pos=stripos($line, 'require')) === true) { 
        $controller = $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: I misinterpreted the documentation on php.net.
Note the following:

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function. 

Means it can eval to FALSE but not TRUE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use !==false instead of ===true
stripos returns the position as an integer if the needle is found. And that's never ===bool.

You might also be interested in PHP's [tokenizer module](https://www.php.net/tokenizer) or the [lexer package](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_LexerGenerator) in the pear repository.

Answer (score 3):

Variable interpolation is only performed on "strings", not 'strings' (note the quotes). i.e.

```
<?php
  $foo = "bar";

  print '$foo';
  print "$foo";
?>
```

prints $foobar. Change your quotes, and all should be well.

Comment: I think the point is that he wanted to avoid interpolation - he's looking for a literal <tt>$table_id</tt> in the file, not looking for the value of the <tt>$table_id</tt> variable.

Answer (score 3):

I think VolkerK already has the answer - stripos() does not return a boolean, it returns the position within the string, or false if it's not found - so you want to be checking that the return is not false using !== (not != as you want to check the type as well).

Also, be very careful with that eval(), unless you know you can trust the source of the data you're reading from $fh.

Otherwise, there could be anything else on that line that you unwittingly eval() - the line could be something like:

```
$table_id = 'foo'; exec('/bin/rm -rf /');
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [PHP docs](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), strpos() and stripos() will return an integer for the position, **OR** a boolean FALSE.

Since 0 (zero) is a valid, and very expect-able index, this function should be used with extreme caution.

Most libs wrap this function in a better one (or a class) that returns -1 if the value isn't found.

e.g. like Javascript's

```
String.indexOf(str)
```

Comment: Why does that help?  If you use it in a boolean context you're still going to get unexpected results if the substring is found at the start of the string, as the position is 0, which will of course equate to false, so you've still got to be sensible.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using the === Argument?

If it is anywhere in the line, it will be an integer.  You're comparing the type also by using ====

From my understand you're asking it "If the position is equal and of the same type as true" which will never work.